# C# + Access запись и чтение массива байт

Tags: c#, база-данных, access, aes

Имеется программа которая шифрует пароли с помощью AES. Этот алгоритм шифрования использует массивы байт. Ключ и вектор инициализации (IV) записываю в поле OLE и они вроде как хранятся там, но в момент когда пытаюсь достать данные выскакивает ошибка.

[image: ошибка]

```
public byte[] GetKeyFromKeyTable(int ID)
{
     byte[] Key;
     DataTable stor = new DataTable();
     string sql = string.Format("Select [EKey] From [KeyTable] Where [Id_Auth]  = '{0}'", ID);
     using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, this.connect))
     {
          OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          stor.Load(dr);
          dr.Close();
          Key = (byte[])stor.Rows[0][0];
     }
     return Key;
}
```

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException не обработано   ErrorCode=-2147217913
>   HResult=-2147217913   Message=Несоответствие типов данных в выражении
>   условия отбора.   Source=Microsoft JET Database Engine   StackTrace:
>          в System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
>   hr)
>          в System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
>   dbParams, Object& executeResult)
>          в System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
>          в System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
>          в System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)
>          в System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>          в System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
>          в master_password.DBase.GetKeyFromKeyTable(Int32 ID) в C:\Users\rmatu\Desktop\PasswordStorage\PasswordStorage\DBase.cs:строка
>   336
>          в PasswordStorage.Main.Main_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) в C:\Users\rmatu\Desktop\PasswordStorage\PasswordStorage\Main.cs:строка
>   86
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>          в MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
>          в MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm.WndProc(Message& m)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)   InnerException:

Comment: Красивая картинка, но лучше бы было, если бы вы выложили код и сообщение об ошибке в привычном формате.

Comment: @0xdb я могу скинуть всё что понадобится, лишь хоть как-то мне подсказали в каком ключе думать

Comment: Воспользуйтесь кнопкой [править](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/635658/edit) и копи-паста сформатированный фрагмент кода.

Comment: @0xdb вот исправил

Comment: Свединия об исключении тоже пожалуйста скопируйте в вопрос.

Comment: @0xdb всё что было

Comment: У вас где-то идет несоответствие типов. Могу предположить что у вас в БД поле Id_Auth числовое а ID строка.

Comment: @Murad нет, поле id_auth числовое, у меня поля логин и пароль (оле поле) и и проблема скорее всего в доступе к ним

Comment: а уберите кавычки в запросе для '{0}'  -> {0}

Comment: @Murad целую ваши мысли просто, сработало

Comment: Всегда рад помочь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> а уберите кавычки в запросе для '{0}' -> {0} – Murad

действительно помогло